# Background image size doesn't fit properly on Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-edge

I have an issue with background image that doesn't fit well ,in chrome and mozilla works fine but in the Microsoft Edge the image doesn't cover the div element.

```
<style type="text/css">
   .BackImg{
    background-image:url('background.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover contain; //doesn't work in microsoft Edge as the chrome or mozilla
    padding: 10px;
   }
  </style>

 <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 BackImg">
       <h2>Header 2</h2>
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 innerDiv">
             <p>Inner div</p>
           </div>
       </div>
     </div> 
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does edge still do the demented "quirks mode" microsoft box model?  What doctype are you using?  I am hoping `<!DOCTYPE html> ` ...

Comment: No there is just a single rendering mode now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the css background-size property you should use just cover, or just contain. Not both.

Cover will cover the background whilst contain is a similar effect but could result in white space.